# Proving convergence using the definition.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying for a test and came upon this question: Prove that

> $${\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n}+3}$$ 
>   converges to $3$ using the definition of convergence.

What I've been trying is

$$\frac{2}{n²} +\frac{4}{n} + 3 -3 = \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{4}{n} =  \frac{4n+2}{n^2}, $$

but that's where I get stuck trying to figure out what epsilon should equal.

Anyone have any tips on how to proceed or maybe redirect how I'm starting? I'm just getting stuck in my scratch work.

Answer (score 2):

You're fine so far. Note that $\frac{4n+2}{n^2} \le  \frac{4n+2n}{n^2}=\frac6n$, for example.

Comment: Thank you, that helps so much! I guess I never thought to manipulate the numerator.